# C# Api for new post to Blogger

Tags: c#, blogger

```
GoogleCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream("secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
        .CreateScoped(BloggerService.Scope.Blogger);
};


BloggerService service = new BloggerService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "test",
    ApiKey = "Key"
});

var newPost = new Post
{
    Title = "Mon nouvel article",
    Content = "Contenu de l'article...",
    Labels = new List<string> { "label1", "label2" }, Blog = new Google.Apis.Blogger.v3.Data.Post.BlogData() { Id = "BlogID" }};


var insertedPost = service.Posts.Insert(newPost, "BlogID").Execute();
```

I get

> The service blogger has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Forbidden. We're sorry, but you don't have permission to access this resource

when I try to post to blogger`

Comment: Is this your actual code? You're missing **at least** a quote (see the syntax-highlighting go nuts at `secrets.json`). This won't even compile.

Comment: misspell when anonymize code.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream("secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{               
    string credPath = "token.json";
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        new[] { BloggerService.Scope.Blogger },
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
}
```

this solve my trouble

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).